# Troubles getting a serie of nested module to working a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, module

I have created a mock-up Shiny app based on a problem that I encounter with real Shiny app I am working on. However, I run into trouble to get it to work when I would like to move stuff out of the general ui- and server function and into a module.

This is the basic version of the Shiny app that is working:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

module_gearcat_UI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  box(
    title = textOutput(ns("box_title")),
    width = 12,
    solidHeader = TRUE,
    collapsible = TRUE,
    DT::DTOutput(ns("gear_DT"))
  )
}

module_gearcat_Server <- function(id, var_gear, selected_rows){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    tbl <- eventReactive(var_gear, {
      mtcars %>% 
        filter(gear == var_gear)      
    })
    
    output$box_title <- renderText({
      var_gear %>% return()
    })
    
    output$gear_DT <- DT::renderDT({
      DT_output <- tbl() %>%
        DT::datatable(
          selection = "multiple",
          style = "bootstrap4",
          options = list(
            dom='t', 
            ordering = FALSE
          )
        ) 
      DT_output %>% return()
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$gear_DT_rows_selected, {
      input$gear_DT_rows_selected %>% print()
      selected_rows[[id]] <<- input$gear_DT_rows_selected
    })
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("list")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  lst <- c(3, 4, 5)
  
  # Initialize reactiveValues to store selected rows
  selected_rows <- reactiveValues()
  for (gear in lst) {
    selected_rows[[paste0("main_", gear)]] <- NULL
  }
  
  output$list <- renderUI({
    lapply(lst, function(gear) {
      fluidRow(
        column(12, module_gearcat_UI(paste0("main_", gear)))
      )
    })
  })
  
  lapply(lst, function(gear) {
    module_gearcat_Server(id = paste0("main_", gear), var_gear = gear, selected_rows)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to move everything that is currently in `uiOutput("list")` to a separate module, but all my attempts failed. I am sure there is a simple trick to do this, but how? Anybody that can enlighten me with a solution direction?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what's the issue. First, at least for your example I don't see any reason to use `renderUI` and `uiOutput`. Instead you could move all the stuff to the UI. Also, I don't see any reason to use a `reactiveValues`. Instead you could return the selected rows as the return value of the module server.

Note: I added a text output to display the returned values.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

module_gearcat_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  box(
    title = textOutput(ns("box_title")),
    width = 12,
    solidHeader = TRUE,
    collapsible = TRUE,
    DT::DTOutput(ns("gear_DT"))
  )
}

module_gearcat_Server <- function(id, var_gear) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    tbl <- reactive({
      mtcars %>%
        filter(gear == var_gear)
    })

    output$box_title <- renderText({
      var_gear
    })

    output$gear_DT <- DT::renderDT({
      tbl() %>%
        DT::datatable(
          selection = "multiple",
          style = "bootstrap4",
          options = list(
            dom = "t",
            ordering = FALSE
          )
        )
    })
    
    return(
      reactive(input$gear_DT_rows_selected)
    )
  })
}

lst <- c(3, 4, 5)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("selected_rows"),
  lapply(lst, function(gear) {
    fluidRow(
      column(12, module_gearcat_UI(paste0("main_", gear)))
    )
  })
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  selected_rows <- lapply(lst, function(gear) {
    module_gearcat_Server(id = paste0("main_", gear), var_gear = gear)
  }) |> 
    setNames(paste0("main_", lst))
  
  output$selected_rows <- renderPrint({
    lapply(selected_rows, \(x) x())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And if you want to wrap or nest in another module then you can do:

```
module_main_ui <- function(id, lst) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  lapply(lst, function(gear) {
    fluidRow(
      column(12, module_gearcat_UI(ns(paste0("main_", gear))))
    )
  })
}

module_main_server <- function(id, lst) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    selected_rows <- lapply(lst, function(gear) {
      module_gearcat_Server(id = paste0("main_", gear), var_gear = gear)
    }) |>
      setNames(paste0("main_", lst))
    
    return(selected_rows)
  })
}

lst <- c(3, 4, 5)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("selected_rows"),
  module_main_ui("main", lst)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  selected_rows <- module_main_server("main", lst)
  
  output$selected_rows <- renderPrint({
    lapply(selected_rows, \(x) x())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. I continued on your second solution and implemented the `reactive` values and added this as a separate answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I continued on @Stefan's answer and implemented `reactive` in the example. My working code below, I hope it is useful for somebody.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

module_gearcat_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  box(
    title = textOutput(ns("box_title")),
    width = 12,
    solidHeader = TRUE,
    collapsible = TRUE,
    DT::DTOutput(ns("gear_DT"))
  )
}
module_gearcat_Server <- function(id, var_gear) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    tbl <- reactive({
      mtcars %>%
        filter(gear == var_gear)
    })
    
    output$box_title <- renderText({
      var_gear
    })
    
    output$gear_DT <- DT::renderDT({
      tbl() %>%
        DT::datatable(
          selection = "multiple",
          style = "bootstrap4",
          options = list(
            dom = "t",
            ordering = FALSE
          )
        )
    })
    
    return(
      reactive(input$gear_DT_rows_selected)
    )
  })
}

module_main_ui <- function(id, lst) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  lapply(lst, function(gear) {
    fluidRow(
      column(12, module_gearcat_UI(ns(paste0("main_", gear))))
    )
  })
}
module_main_server <- function(id, lst) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    selected_rows <- lapply(lst, function(gear) {
      module_gearcat_Server(id = paste0("main_", gear), var_gear = gear)
    }) |>
      setNames(paste0("main_", lst))
    
    return(selected_rows)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  # verbatimTextOutput("selected_rows"),
  # uiOutput("module_ui"),  
  # hr(), 
  verbatimTextOutput("selected_rows_reactive"), 
  uiOutput("module_ui_reactive")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # # Simple version
  # lst <- c(3, 4, 5)
  # selected_rows <- module_main_server("main", lst)
  # output$module_ui <- renderUI({
  #   module_main_ui("main", lst)
  # })
  # output$selected_rows <- renderPrint({
  #   lapply(selected_rows, \(x) x())
  # })
  
  # Version: lst is reactive
  lst_reactive <- reactive({
    list <- c(3,4,5) %>% as_tibble()
    selection <- list %>% filter(value %in% c(3, 5, 8, 9)) %>% pull(value)
    selection %>% return()
  })
  observe({})
  selected_rows_reactive <- reactive(
    module_main_server("main_reactive", lst_reactive())
  )

  output$module_ui_reactive <- renderUI({
    module_main_ui("main_reactive", lst_reactive())
  })
  output$selected_rows_reactive <- renderPrint({
    lapply(selected_rows_reactive(), \(x) x())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```